# Email showing Array instead of image

Tags: php, forms

I have a contact from that allows users to add an attachment but the email I receive shows Array where the image id should be.

Form details below.

```
First Name: gffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
Last Name: williams
Email: jessie747williams@gmail.com
Subject: hello
Image: Array (HERE) shousd show the image like apple.jpg
Comments: fd
```

```php
     //Settings
    $max_allowed_file_size = 100; // size in KB
    $allowed_extensions = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "bmp");
    //Validations
    if($size_of_uploaded_file > $max_allowed_file_size )
    {
      $errors .= "\n Size of file should be less than $max_allowed_file_size";
    }
    //------ Validate the file extension -----
    $allowed_ext = false;
    for($i=0; $i<sizeof($allowed_extensions); $i++)
    {
      if(strcasecmp($allowed_extensions[$i],$type_of_uploaded_file) == 0)
      {
        $allowed_ext = true;
      }
    }
    if(!$allowed_ext)
    {
      $errors .= "\n The uploaded file is not supported file type. ".
      " Only the following file types are supported: ".implode(',',$allowed_extensions);
    }

      if(!empty($_FILES['uploaded_file']))
      {
        $path = "uploads/";
        $path = $path . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $path)) {
          header("Location: https://www.website.com/thank-you-image/");
        } else{
            echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
        }
      }

    ?>

    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

        // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
        $email_to = "xxx@gmail.com";
        $email_subject = "Add my image to xxx";
     header("Location: https://www.website.com/thank-you-image/");

        function died($error) {
            // your error code can go here
            echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
            echo "These errors appear below.</br></br>";
            echo $error."</br></br>";
            echo "Please go back and fix these errors.</br></br>";
            die();
        }


        // validation expected data exists
        if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||
            !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||
            !isset($_POST['subject']) ||
            !isset($_POST['email']) ||
            !isset($_FILES['uploaded_file']) ||
            !isset($_POST['comments'])) {
            died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       
        }



        $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required
        $last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required
        $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
        $subject = $_POST['subject']; // required
        $uploaded_file = $_FILES['uploaded_file']; // required
        $comments = $_POST['comments']; // required

        $error_message = "";
        $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';

      if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
        $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.</br>';
      }

        $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";

      if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {
        $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.</br>';
      }

      if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {
        $error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.</br>';
      }

     if(!preg_match($string_exp,$subject)) {
        $error_message .= 'The Subject you entered does not appear to be valid.</br>';
      }

      if(strlen($comments) < 2) {
        $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.</br>';
      }

      if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
        died($error_message);
      }

        $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";


        function clean_string($string) {
          $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
          return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
        }

        $email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
        $email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";
        $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
        $email_message .= "Subject: ".clean_string($subject)."\n";
        $email_message .= "Image: ".clean_string($uploaded_file)."\n";
        $email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";

    // create email headers
    $headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
    'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
    ?>

    <!-- include your own success html here -->

    Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.
```

Comment: This is of course going to give you an array `$uploaded_file = $_FILES['uploaded_file'];`

Comment: How should it be. Thanks

Comment: What do you want to attach in `"Image: ".clean_string($uploaded_file)."\n";`? Is it the file name or an HTML image?

Comment: I want the file name. thx

Answer (score 1):

So change

```
"Image: ".clean_string($uploaded_file)."\n";
```

to

```
"Image: ".clean_string($uploaded_file['name'])."\n";
```

**Update:**

Also, add `<script>` and `</script>` to your `$bad` variable in `clean_string()` function.

```
$bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href","<script>","</script>");
```

Although email service providers strip Javascript code, but just an extra security measure.

Comment: @JessieWilliams don't forget to set the question as correct one, then.

Answer (score 1):

Simply change:

```php
$uploaded_file = $_FILES['uploaded_file'];
```

to

```php
$uploaded_file = $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name'];
```